# How can I fix 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Serializable' error when running gatling jar

Tags: karate

I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Serializable error when running gatling jar.

Using custom java binaries from >> /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.275.b01-0.el6_10.x86_64/bin
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Serializable

```
<profile>
            <id>buildTest</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.gatling.highcharts</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                    <version>${gratlin.charts}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>karate-junit4</artifactId>
                    <version>${karate.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>karate-gatling</artifactId>
                    <version>${karate.version}</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
                            <artifactId>gatling-commons</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
                            <artifactId>gatling-charts</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
                            <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gatling-app</artifactId>
                    <version>${gratlin.app.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
                    <version>2.13.6</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <testResources>
                    <testResource>
                        <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                        <excludes>
                            <!--<exclude>**/*.java</exclude>-->
                        </excludes>
                    </testResource>
                </testResources>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>4.5.6</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                                <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <jvmArgs>
                                <jvmArg>-Xms512m</jvmArg>
                                <jvmArg>-Xmx2048m</jvmArg>
                            </jvmArgs>
                            <recompileMode>incremental</recompileMode>
                            <useZincServer>true</useZincServer>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.4.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>shade</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>4.1.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <simulationsFolder>src/test/scala</simulationsFolder>
                            <runMultipleSimulations>true</runMultipleSimulations>
                            <includes>
                                <include>orderServices.GetOrderSimulation</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

Somehow after running mvn clean install -P buildTest, the generated jar does not have Serializable class.

Comment: honestly have no idea. this may be because of your java install, and `JAVA_HOME` not pointing to the right place etc. see if you can get this working on another machine

Comment: scala/Serializable is not found in scala-libray in 2.13.0 version onwards.. 
But even when i include 2.12.17 jar, i am getting
```
java.io.IOException: Scala signature PreDef has wrong version
```

Comment: lets hope someone else here can help you